# Interesting: What's wrong with this sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Born of Ibuza parents in Nigeria, novelist Buchi Emeta moved to England in **1962, since which she has lived in North London**.

The part in bold should be corrected/improved-accroding to the SAT mcq answer sheet-as "1962, and has lived in North London since then". But I don't know what's wrong with the original.

Comment: First: you need spaces after your commas. Second, it would be better to use StackExchange's typographic tools to emphasize parts of your sentence, such as **bold** or *italics*, rather than ALL CAPS. Third, I personally wouldn't say the original formulation is wrong, per se, but it is clumsy and awkward.

Comment: Why on earth is "parents" capitalised?

Comment: The author is trying to pack too much information into one sentence with a relative clause, which invokes an arcane grammatical structure and distracts the reader. That's poor writing practice. Two sentences, conjoined in writing with a semicolon, sounds like the way one would say it; and if it sounds good, it **is** good, as the Duke put. Thus, _Born of Ibuza parents in Nigeria, novelist Buchi Emeta moved to England in 1962; since then she has lived in North London._

Answer (score 3):

The text can be corrected easily by inserting a missing word (which is what the error is — there's a word missing):

> Born of Ibuza Parents in Nigeria, novelist Buchi Emeta moved to England in 1962, **since which time** she has lived in North London.

*Which* here relates *time* to *1962.* OED calls this the "ordinary relative adjective":

> **III.** Relative uses.
>    * as simple relative.
>    **6.** *adj.* The ordinary relative adj.

The entry was last updated in 1923, so its final citation of 1892 was not all that dated when it was edited. After nearly a century, this usage is beginning to be very dated.

These days the sentence would **probably** use *since when* instead of *since which time,* although I find that awkward for some reason and would prefer *which time,* given the sentence including *which.* Unfortunately that means that there are two potential answers to "What's the problem here?"

Comment: so what is the error in the original,in general terms?Vague pronoun?Other examples?I need to see it from a proof reading perspective for the SAT.And how does the correction I mentioned Improve the original?

Comment: What does _which_ refer to in the original? Which _what_? The phrase "which time" fits and makes sense, although you could equally just have written "when" instead ... but in the original the _which_ is dangling.

Comment: Edited. Unfortunately ESL SAT tests seem often to be poorly designed.

Comment: Over 1000 written instances of [*in 1970 since **when***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+1970+since+when%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) imply that not everyone finds the usage "awkward". And that's just for one specific year - doubtless there will be thousands more for different years, and for other ways of referring to a specific point in (past) time. I don't find it at all unusual - it seems perfectly natural to me in all registers, whereas *since which **time*** seems to unavoidably carry overtones of "formal" usage.

Comment: 'which' refers to 1962?

Comment: @VidupaSamarasinghe No, *time* refers to 1962, and it is *which* that makes that reference.

Answer (score 0):

*Since which* is the problem.  'Which' refers to a thing, not a time. You could rephrase to

> ..England in 1962, and since then has lived in North London.

or,

> ..England in 1962, having lived in North London ever since.

Comment: can a year not be a thing?

Comment: A year is a unit of time, yes.  But to reference the time *since* a certain year, you are referring to the span of time following, not the particular year itself.

Comment: Correlatives is almost certainly out of date but think of family groups: That thing, that, what? which.  That place, there, where? where.

Answer (score 0):

The standard phrase is "since which *time*..."

But its use is [on the decline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=since%20which%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csince%20which%20time%3B%2Cc0).